# UI Design Patterns for image upload and management

Tags: design-patterns

We are looking for best in class design patterns for image upload and management for advertising? Specifically services that convey to the user all the needed sizes and aspect ratios for their campaigns and then a preview and management tool for each individual image or piece of creative/

Suggestions? Links?

Enclosed[image] is  very rudimentary but functional example from RevMob.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit better what do you want? and what do you want to offer to your users.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking us to come up with an Asset Management System UI. That's way too broad to be answered in a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand that you want users to upload two images - one for each orientation? This might go against some user experience issues (because you're having them do more work outside your app).

I take it that you probably want a specific aspect ratio for all images in the same campaign, which looks like 4:3 and 3:4 above. You could require the user to upload photos of the required aspect ratios (to ensure that everything in the photo they upload will be shown). But then again, this is an extra responsibility on the user. Alternatively, you can let them upload any image of any dimension, but you will need to give them cropping (with aspect ratio locked) capabilities to have them set what part of the picture to be shown in the final ad.